# Cannot run test remotely in Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, testing, visual-studio-2017

Installed: TestAgent 2017, TestController 2017. Firewall: Disabled everywhere. Wrote test:

```
public void TestMethod1()
{
     Assert.IsFalse(false);
}
```

Try to run this test on remote agent from VS 2017 and get in the output:

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

TestController log:

```
I, 6516, 45, 2018/01/23, 14:49:37.723, WINTCNN\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Creating ControllerExecution for TestRun a007769d-4e55-4dc9-8d5a-db42b5b3f10e
I, 6516, 45, 2018/01/23, 14:49:37.723, WINTCNN\QTController.exe, ControllerSpooledJob: creating spooled job for test run 'akozlov@WKS04 2018-01-23 14:49:22'
I, 6516, 45, 2018/01/23, 14:49:37.723, WINTCNN\QTController.exe, ControllerObject: Queuing TestRun a007769d-4e55-4dc9-8d5a-db42b5b3f10e
```

And nothing more related to test execution

When I try the same test from VS 2015 everything goes OK. And TestController log has many more records.

What prevents my test from executing from VS 2017?

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved so: 

I installed Visual Studio Test Controller on machine where I have Visual Studio IDE installed https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=TestController&rel=15

And the problem disappeared.

Then I uninstalled Test Controller and the tests continued to pass well.

The same was done on several other machines.

Miracles from (C)Microsoft.